# Ckan Offline install from Zip file using python ckan/setup.py install

Tags: python, ckan

I get this error message on the CMD when I try to install the ckan package from source.

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  File "c:\users\blissmen.anonymous\envs\default\lib\site-packages\ckan-2.3a-py3
.4.egg\ckan\model\related.py", line 91
    raise Exception, 'Unable to attach `related_count` to Package class.'
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "c:\users\blissmen.anonymous\envs\default\lib\site-p`enter code here`ackages\ckan-2.3a-py3
.4.egg\ckan\new_tests\logic\test_validators.py", line 158
    100L,
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "c:\users\blissmen.anonymous\envs\default\lib\site-packages\ckan-2.3a-py3
.4.egg\ckan\pastertemplates\__init__.py", line 38
    print "\nError: Expected the project name to start with 'ckanext-'"
                                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "c:\users\blissmen.anonymous\envs\default\lib\site-packages\ckan-2.3a-py3
.4.egg\ckan\tests\wsgi_ckanclient.py", line 29
    print "ckanclient: Opening %s" % location
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "c:\users\blissmen.anonymous\envs\default\lib\site-packages\ckan-2.3a-py3
.4.egg\ckan\tests\__init__.py", line 82
    raise Exception, "Couldn't execute cmd: %s: %s" % (cmd, output)
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "c:\users\blissmen.anonymous\envs\default\lib\site-packages\ckan-2.3a-py3
.4.egg\ckan\tests\functional\test_cors.py", line 19
    print headers
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "c:\users\blissmen.anonymous\envs\default\lib\site-packages\ckan-2.3a-py3
.4.egg\ckan\tests\functional\test_group.py", line 284
    print offset
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "c:\users\blissmen.anonymous\envs\default\lib\site-packages\ckan-2.3a-py3
.4.egg\ckan\tests\functional\test_package.py", line 231
    print pkg_by_name_main
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "c:\users\blissmen.anonymous\envs\default\lib\site-packages\ckan-2.3a-py3
.4.egg\ckan\tests\functional\test_related.py", line 48
    print '@@@@', offset
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "c:\users\blissmen.anonymous\envs\default\lib\site-packages\ckan-2.3a-py3
.4.egg\ckan\tests\functional\test_revision.py", line 82
    print "\nThe first response (list):\n\n"
                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "c:\users\blissmen.anonymous\envs\default\lib\site-packages\ckan-2.3a-py3
.4.egg\ckan\tests\functional\test_search.py", line 88
    print offset
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "c:\users\blissmen.anonymous\envs\default\lib\site-packages\ckan-2.3a-py3
.4.egg\ckan\tests\functional\api\base.py", line 187
    except ValueError, inst:
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "c:\users\blissmen.anonymous\envs\default\lib\site-packages\ckan-2.3a-py3
.4.egg\ckan\tests\functional\api\test_activity.py", line 226
    print '@@@@@@@@', extra_environ
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "c:\users\blissmen.anonymous\envs\default\lib\site-packages\ckan-2.3a-py3
.4.egg\ckan\tests\functional\api\test_package_search.py", line 226
    print offset
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "c:\users\blissmen.anonymous\envs\default\lib\site-packages\ckan-2.3a-py3
.4.egg\ckan\tests\functional\api\test_user.py", line 33
    print response.json
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "c:\users\blissmen.anonymous\envs\default\lib\site-packages\ckan-2.3a-py3
.4.egg\ckan\tests\functional\api\model\test_package.py", line 641
    print package1_offset, package2_data
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "c:\users\blissmen.anonymous\envs\default\lib\site-packages\ckan-2.3a-py3
.4.egg\ckan\tests\functional\api\model\test_relationships.py", line 256
    print res.body
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "c:\users\blissmen.anonymous\envs\default\lib\site-packages\ckan-2.3a-py3
.4.egg\ckan\tests\lib\test_dictization.py", line 250
    print "\n".join(unified_diff(pformat(result).split("\n"), pformat(self.packa
ge_expected).split("\n")))
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "c:\users\blissmen.anonymous\envs\default\lib\site-packages\ckan-2.3a-py3
.4.egg\ckan\tests\lib\test_field_types.py", line 19
    ('2/11/67 9:04', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM', [1967, 11, 2, 9, 04]),
                                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid token

  File "c:\users\blissmen.anonymous\envs\default\lib\site-packages\ckan-2.3a-py3
.4.egg\ckan\tests\lib\test_navl.py", line 98
    print set(full_schema.keys()) - set(data.keys())
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "c:\users\blissmen.anonymous\envs\default\lib\site-packages\ckan-2.3a-py3
.4.egg\ckan\tests\lib\test_solr_schema_version.py", line 40
    except SearchError,e:
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "c:\users\blissmen.anonymous\envs\default\lib\site-packages\ckan-2.3a-py3
.4.egg\ckan\tests\lib\test_solr_search_index.py", line 25
    except socket.error, e:
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "c:\users\blissmen.anonymous\envs\default\lib\site-packages\ckan-2.3a-py3
.4.egg\ckan\tests\logic\test_action.py", line 205
    print package_created
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "c:\users\blissmen.anonymous\envs\default\lib\site-packages\ckan-2.3a-py3
.4.egg\ckan\tests\logic\test_auth.py", line 399
    print model.Session.query(model.Member).filter_by(state='deleted').all()
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "c:\users\blissmen.anonymous\envs\default\lib\site-packages\ckan-2.3a-py3
.4.egg\ckan\tests\misc\test_sync.py", line 42
    except urllib2.URLError, e:
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "c:\users\blissmen.anonymous\envs\default\lib\site-packages\ckan-2.3a-py3
.4.egg\ckan\tests\models\test_resource.py", line 136
    print lastres
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "c:\users\blissmen.anonymous\envs\default\lib\site-packages\ckan-2.3a-py3
.4.egg\ckanext\datapusher\plugin.py", line 113
    except p.toolkit.ValidationError, e:
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "c:\users\blissmen.anonymous\envs\default\lib\site-packages\ckan-2.3a-py3
.4.egg\ckanext\datapusher\logic\action.py", line 94
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError, e:
                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "c:\users\blissmen.anonymous\envs\default\lib\site-packages\ckan-2.3a-py3
.4.egg\ckanext\datapusher\tests\test.py", line 169
    print res.body
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "c:\users\blissmen.anonymous\envs\default\lib\site-packages\ckan-2.3a-py3
.4.egg\ckanext\datastore\db.py", line 148
    except ProgrammingError, e:
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "c:\users\blissmen.anonymous\envs\default\lib\site-packages\ckan-2.3a-py3
.4.egg\ckanext\example_theme\v03_jinja\plugin.py", line 1
    ../v02_empty_template/plugin.py
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "c:\users\blissmen.anonymous\envs\default\lib\site-packages\ckan-2.3a-py3
.4.egg\ckanext\example_theme\v04_ckan_extends\plugin.py", line 1
    ../v03_jinja/plugin.py
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "c:\users\blissmen.anonymous\envs\default\lib\site-packages\ckan-2.3a-py3
.4.egg\ckanext\example_theme\v05_block\plugin.py", line 1
    ../v04_ckan_extends/plugin.py
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "c:\users\blissmen.anonymous\envs\default\lib\site-packages\ckan-2.3a-py3
.4.egg\ckanext\example_theme\v06_super\plugin.py", line 1
    ../v05_block/plugin.py
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "c:\users\blissmen.anonymous\envs\default\lib\site-packages\ckan-2.3a-py3
.4.egg\ckanext\example_theme\v07_helper_function\plugin.py", line 1
    ../v06_super/plugin.py
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "c:\users\blissmen.anonymous\envs\default\lib\site-packages\ckan-2.3a-py3
.4.egg\ckanext\example_theme\v09_snippet\plugin.py", line 1
    ../v08_custom_helper_function/plugin.py
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "c:\users\blissmen.anonymous\envs\default\lib\site-packages\ckan-2.3a-py3
.4.egg\ckanext\example_theme\v10_custom_snippet\plugin.py", line 1
    ../v09_snippet/plugin.py
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "c:\users\blissmen.anonymous\envs\default\lib\site-packages\ckan-2.3a-py3
.4.egg\ckanext\example_theme\v11_HTML_and_CSS\plugin.py", line 1
    ../v10_custom_snippet/plugin.py
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "c:\users\blissmen.anonymous\envs\default\lib\site-packages\ckan-2.3a-py3
.4.egg\ckanext\example_theme\v13_custom_css\plugin.py", line 1
    ../v12_extra_public_dir/plugin.py
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "c:\users\blissmen.anonymous\envs\default\lib\site-packages\ckan-2.3a-py3
.4.egg\ckanext\example_theme\v14_more_custom_css\plugin.py", line 1
    ../v13_custom_css/plugin.py
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "c:\users\blissmen.anonymous\envs\default\lib\site-packages\ckan-2.3a-py3
.4.egg\ckanext\example_theme\v17_popover\plugin.py", line 1
    ../v16_initialize_a_javascript_module/plugin.py
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "c:\users\blissmen.anonymous\envs\default\lib\site-packages\ckan-2.3a-py3
.4.egg\ckanext\example_theme\v18_snippet_api\plugin.py", line 1
    ../v17_popover/plugin.py
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "c:\users\blissmen.anonymous\envs\default\lib\site-packages\ckan-2.3a-py3
.4.egg\ckanext\example_theme\v19_01_error\plugin.py", line 1
    ../v18_snippet_api/plugin.py
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "c:\users\blissmen.anonymous\envs\default\lib\site-packages\ckan-2.3a-py3
.4.egg\ckanext\example_theme\v19_02_error_handling\plugin.py", line 1
    ../v19_01_error/plugin.py
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "c:\users\blissmen.anonymous\envs\default\lib\site-packages\ckan-2.3a-py3
.4.egg\ckanext\example_theme\v20_pubsub\plugin.py", line 1
    ../v19_02_error_handling/plugin.py
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "c:\users\blissmen.anonymous\envs\default\lib\site-packages\ckan-2.3a-py3
.4.egg\ckanext\example_theme\v21_custom_jquery_plugin\plugin.py", line 1
    ../v20_pubsub/plugin.py
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "c:\users\blissmen.anonymous\envs\default\lib\site-packages\ckan-2.3a-py3
.4.egg\ckanext\resourceproxy\controller.py", line 65
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError, error:
                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

ckan 2.3a is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing ckan-admin-script.py script to C:\Users\blissmen.Anonymous\Envs\Defau
lt\Scripts
Installing ckan-admin.exe script to C:\Users\blissmen.Anonymous\Envs\Default\Scr
ipts
Installing ckan-admin.exe.manifest script to C:\Users\blissmen.Anonymous\Envs\De
fault\Scripts

Installed c:\users\blissmen.anonymous\envs\default\lib\site-packages\ckan-2.3a-p
y3.4.egg
Processing dependencies for ckan==2.3a
Finished processing dependencies for ckan==2.3a
```

Answer (score 1):

These syntax errors show that your package was written for Python 2, but apparently you're trying to install it with Python 3.4.

You should install Python 2.7 and try again.